# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Inchoo_Orders_Helper_Data in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error, helper

I am using inchoo order extension in magento 1.9 and it's throwing this fatal error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Inchoo_Orders_Helper_Data' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/vitadeals/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
<modules>
    <Inchoo_Orders>
        <version>0.0.0.1</version>
    </Inchoo_Orders>
</modules>

<global>
    <models>
        <inchoo_orders>
            <class>Inchoo_Orders_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>inchoo_orders_resource</resourceModel>
        </inchoo_orders>
    </models>

    <resources>
        <inchoo_orders_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Inchoo_Orders</module>
            </setup>
        </inchoo_orders_setup>
    </resources>

    <blocks>
        <inchoo_orders>
            <class>Inchoo_Orders_Block</class>
        </inchoo_orders>
    </blocks>

    <helpers>
        <inchoo_orders>
            <class>Inchoo_Orders_Helper</class>
        </inchoo_orders>
    </helpers>
</global>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <inchoo_orders before="Mage_Adminhtml">Inchoo_Orders_Adminhtml</inchoo_orders>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

**Data.php**

```
<?php
class Inchoo_Orders_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

and from here helper function class is calling.

```
$helper = Mage::helper('inchoo_orders');
```

Please help guys.

Comment: Do you have your `app/etc/modules/Inchoo_Orders.xml` in place? Like Cm_RedisSession.xml? If you go into your database you will be able to tell if magento has loaded your module with `select code from core_resource where code like '%inchoo%';`

Comment: let me check @LukeRodgers

Comment: It returns "inchoo_orders_setup" . What is this mean @LukeRodgers

Comment: It means your module is correctly installed within magento. I can see the sample `config.xml` you posted does not contain a `</config>` tag, is that an error in your stackoverflow post? 

Have you remembered to flush the caches by deleting the var/cache directory?

Comment: Yes Luke i didn't post whole config.xml so Luke do you have solution of my problem. If you have please please guide me to solve my problem

Comment: Check the code pool in your `app/etc/modules/Inchoo_Orders.xml`. And make sure you have placed your module in correct code pool.